# Dart: Is there a way to negate and return a boolean in a single line?

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

Is there a way to write the follwoing funciton as a single line, using the fat arrow (=>) notation?

```
 bool tick() {
   _tick = !_tick;
   return _tick;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `thick()` method will negate `_tick` and return the newly assigned value:

```dart
bool tick() => _tick = !_tick;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
bool tick() => !_tick;
```

`_tick` should be defined, and this function will return negated value. So you have to assign the result in order to negate. Like this:

```
void main() {
  bool _tick = true;
  _tick = tick(_tick);
  print(_tick); 
  _tick = tick(_tick);
  print(_tick); 
}

bool tick(tick) => !tick;
```

The above will print:

```
false
true
```

If you'd like to have a variable declared and have this negated in a function you can try:

```
class Tick {
  bool tick;
  Tick(this.tick);
}

void tick(Tick data) => data.tick = !data.tick;

main() {
  var data = new Tick(true);
  print(data.tick); // true
  tick(data);
  print(data.tick); // false
  tick(data);
  print(data.tick); // true
}
```

Comment: Close, but it's not the same.This function would return the same value if I call it repeatedly. My original function returns alternating values if I call it repeatedly.

Comment: Where is `_tick` defined? Your original code doesn't show that.